# Windows 10/Apache24/PHP 7.4.19 not loading mysqli

Tags: php, windows, mysqli, apache2.4

I have a WAMP stack that I put together on my windows 10 machine. I loaded MySQL, Apache24 and PHP. MySQL, Apache and PHP work BUT I cannot get the extensions to load. I did set extension_dir in php.ini. I tried extension=mysqli and extension=php_mysqli.dll but neither are working. In fact, I don't think any of the extensions are loading.

PHP is installed is C:\php. Apache is in C:\Apache24.

Here's what I think the relevant portions of my PHP.ini are. Everything else is default:

```
[PHP]

extension_dir = "C:\php\ext\"

;extension=bz2
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

Comment: Try to run `php --ini` to check if your configuration is loaded. And then also try `phpinfo()` on server/browser because many times you have diffrent config for cli and server php versions.

Comment: OK. php.exe --ini shows c:\php\php.ini BUT phpinfo() shows blank in terms of the ini file. What do I need to set to get phpinfo to read that .ini file?

Comment: Most times php-cli and server are configured different. You can set `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR ` environemnt variable and restart your server or try checking out more info in the [PHP Manual - The configuration file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)

Comment: OK, I got it. I added a PHPIniDir directive to httpd.conf and that loaded it. Now my app works. -- THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

You can see this in the comments above but just in case, here's how I fixed this:

1. PHPInfo() showed that no php.ini was being loaded.
2. I added the PHPIniDir directive to the https.conf file and the world was a happy place.

Hope this answer helps someone else!

And thanks to Code Spirit who gave me the clues I needed to figure it out.

Comment: Also, I would like to note that **symlink** to `php.ini` did not work in my case. Once I replaced it with NTFS **hardlink**, everything worked.